# a4j:commandButton click works only if it is the first click on the page

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am upgrading to JSF RichFaces 4.

```
<h:panelGrid width="100%" columnClasses="closeWindow">
    <a4j:commandButton value="#{applicationController.bundle.closeWindow}"
                       action="#{clienteController.closeWindow}"
                       render="clientesForm :customerPanel"
                       oncomplete="#{rich:component('clienteDetalhePanel')}.hide();" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

This is a button on a rich:popupPanel. The action method gets called for every click. But, the oncomplete( panel getting hidden) only works if this is the first click on the page.  If I do any thing else on the page, like save , and then click this button, then the panel is not hidden anymore. It just stays there.

Please note I have been following BalusC's instructions to avoid the view state getting lost, which was my original problem, but that was fixed by adding form and panel to the render. But now I have this problem.

Please help.

Comment: Does the component 'clientDetalhePanel' gets rerendered on those other actions?

Comment: Thanks @W vd L .  Yes, clientDetalhePanel  gets rerendered on the other actions on the page.   The clientDetalhePanel is a popup panel. The intention is to hide this panel when 'close window' button is clicked. But that does not happen if I click this button after any other button on the popup panel is clicked.

Comment: the component in the button gets 'detached'when you rerender its component without also rerendering the button. (you could say the component and button are desynced)

Comment: If you use jQuery, try to toggle it with jQuery.  If you need an example i can give it tomorrow.